# Where to post my question regarding PDF document version control

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want a few suggestion as to what is the best cloud based version control app for PDF files. In which site should I post my question?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net may help you if you already know of one.

Answer (score 5):

Nowhere, other than https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Asking for product recommendations is generally discouraged (more so on some sites than others) as it invites spam and link rot.

Search engines are designed to aggregate links to resources while excising worthless spam and keeping search results up-to-date.  The best solution is to use search engines to conduct your research, identify the resources that appear to best suit your needs, then test them.

Answer (score -3):

Depending upon your intended use of it and (thus) how you ask the question, any of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). But be careful of how you ask to ensure there should be a "right" answer and not just "opinions".

Comment: Software recs is probably the only correct answer if OP is asking what the _best_ one is.